# Finding a non-recursive closed from expression for repeating patterns with gaps

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Consider the example sequence $1\ 2\ 6\ 7\ 11\ 12\ ...\ [5+a_{n-2}]$. It seem obvious that this sequence can be generated with the following recursive method...

$$
\begin{align}
a_0 & = 1\\
a_1 & = 2\\
a_n & = a_{(n-2)} + 5
\end{align}
$$

In general any arbitrary sequence with `I` initial conditions that repeats every `R` could be generated with

$$
\begin{align}
a_{0..I} & = \text{initial values...}\\
a_n & = a_{(n-I)} + R
\end{align}
$$

WolframAlpha was good enough to generate a solution for my example sequnce in the form of...

$$
a_n = 1/4 (-9-3 (-1)^n+10 n)
$$

However, I am searching for a general formula/algorithm. Using generating functions I can get as far as...

$$
A(x) = (1-x^I)^{-1} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{k = I} {(a_kx^k)} - \frac {Rx^I} {x-1} \right]
$$

At least I hope that's right. Honestly I am struggling to map the simple sample sequence to the correct expresson. I am guessing there is either a general formula/process or it is provably "hard."

So, how do you solve this in general? Any hints on the particular case would be nice too. Is there a name for this type of sequence?

Comment: Use $\cos \frac{k}{n} \pi $ to get period-n functions that are linearly independent, and solve the system for initial terms.

Comment: Example please? That was my initial thought too. Last time I tried that the individual waves interfered with each other over the intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the period be $p$ (not necessarily prime)

As you noticed, you can break down your recurrence into a purely periodic aspect, and a 'constant' on consecutive terms aspect. The constant part is easily dealt with using $ r \lfloor \frac{n-1}{p} \rfloor $, where $r$ is the amount in which it increases after each period.

Let $\omega$ be a primitive pth root of unity. Consider the $p-$tuple $A_k = (\omega^k, \omega^{2k}, \ldots , \omega^{pk} ) $, for $1 \leq k \leq p$. Then, these $p$ tuples are linearly independent, which follows from considering the Vandermonde determinant. Hence, the initial terms can be written as a linear combination of these terms.

E.g. In your example of $1, 2, 6, 7, \ldots$, we have $p = 2$ and $r=5$. We have $-1$ is the primitive 2nd root of unity, and so $A_1 = (-1,1) $ and $A_2 = (1,1)$. We can form $(1,2) = \frac{1}{2} A_1 + \frac{ 3}{2} A_2$.

Hence, your general term is $\frac{1}{2} (-1)^n + \frac{3}{2} (1)^n + 5\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$

---

If you do not want the floor function to be involved, you can simply use $\frac{rn}{p}$, which will change your initial values slightly. In this case, the terms have the form

$$ -\frac{3}{2} + \frac{5}{2}, -3 + \frac{5\times 2}{2}, -\frac{3}{2} + \frac{5\times 3}{2}, -3 + \frac{5\times 4}{2}, \ldots $$

We can form $(-\frac{3}{2}, -3) = \frac{-3}{4} A_1 + \frac{-9}{4} A_2$.

Hence, your general term is $\frac{-3}{4} (-1)^n + \frac{-9}{4} (1)^n + \frac{5n}{2}$, which agrees with Wolfram.